# Camel Exchange properties thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I am fairly new to camel so may be it is silly mistake. But I have tried to look for it online but couldn't find the solution anywhere.

I have a route which calls a bean that reads a json array from a json payload and then store its elements in an exchange property as a String. This property will be accessed by another bean later in another route where I check if certain values are present in it or not and based on the outcome take a decision on how to transform outgoing payload.

The problem: I have noticed a scenario where I send two messages back to back and my service picks up and start processing them in separate threads (say 1 and 2). Now sometimes if thread 1 is still in progress, thread 2 overrides the exchange property which cause the output of thread 1 to mess up.
Most of the time it works fine but some times this behavior can be observed.

I was thinking that exchange will take care of thread safety if I use exchange property to carry a value into another route. But looks like its not, any idea what I should do to make sure that exchange property does not get override by another thread.

```
    //in bean A (used by route a)
    exchange.setProperty("elems", elems);

    //in bean B (used by route b which comes after route a)
    String productElements = (String) exchange.getProperty("elems");
```

Comment: Smells like your bean is maybe not thread safe, but its a bit harder to tell when you haven't showed as much code how your beans are and the Camel routes etc. But an exchange property is associated with this exchange only for its entire lifetime.

Comment: you are right. I found out that bean B was saving exchange property into a class level static variable 'productElements' and thats why sometimes other threads change its value. When I moved it inside the function to make it a local variable everything worked fine. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Two Approaches Which I can suggest will be :-

1. You can do deep cloning for your camel exchange object ( may be body ) using SerializationUtils or using normal new operator.
2. In your route use, 

.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ABC.class) 
and immediate
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, ABC.class)

These both approaches worked for me like a charm.